# Writing if / ifelse function in R

Tags: r, function, variables, if-statement, dataframe

I am attempting to write a function in order to create a variable (BBDR) based on the conditions of another variable (Site0) using the if function. I have the following code using the if function.

```
x1 <- (africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0)/29
x2 <- (africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0)/22
x3 <- (africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0)/34
x4 <- (africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0)/30


F1 <- function(y){
if(africanaDamRate$Site0==1){africanaDamRate$BBDR<-x1}
if(africanaDamRate$Site0==2){africanaDamRate$BBDR<-x2}
if(africanaDamRate$Site0==3){africanaDamRate$BBDR<-x3}
if(africanaDamRate$Site0==4){africanaDamRate$BBDR<-x4}
}


africanaDamRate$BBDR<-F1(y)
```

But when I attempt this code I receive "The condition has length greater than 1..."

I have also attempted using the ifelse function with the following code:

```
africanaDamRate$BBDR<-ifelse(c(africanaDamRate$Site0==1, x1, NA), c(africanaDamRate$Site0==2, x2, NA), c(africanaDamRate$Site0==3, x3, NA), c(africanaDamRate$Site0==4, x4, NA))
```

But get the "unused argument" error.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can do this (without subsetting)? Thanks so much!

Ryan

Comment: `africanaDamRate$BBDR <- (africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0) / (as.numeric(africanaDamRate$Site0) * 10)`

Comment: Edits invalidated the above suggestion, but it is easily adaptable `(africanaDamRate$BB6-africanaDamRate$BB0)/c(29,22,34,30)[africanaDamRate$Site0]`

Comment: Assuming no exploitable pattern though, the R-ish way would be `data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)[cbind(seq_along(sites),sites)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ifelse statement is wrong. It could be written like this:

```
africanaDamRate$BBDR <- ifelse(africanaDamRate$Site0 == 1, x1, 
                               ifelse(africanaDamRate$Site0 == 2, x2, 
                                      ifelse(africanaDamRate$Site0 == 3, x3, 
                                             ifelse(africanaDamRate$Site0 == 4, x4, NA))))
```

Comment: But really laterow's comment on the question is superior

Comment: @RyanRothman, if this answers your question, click to accept the answer. It also helps your reputation on SO

Comment: @phiver I guess not.  But that approach could be generalized.

Comment: @phiver The generalized approach being what A. Webb suggests.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. Greatly appreciated!